# iterate on two sequences at once

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bunch of files `aaa`, `aab`, `aad`, ... (note, no `aac`) or generalizing in terms of a glob all the files matched by `a[a-z][a-z]` where not every file is present, and I'd like to rename them in a more compact way, that is  `mv aad aac` etc etc

I could use a different approach (Pythonish pseudocode follows)

```
from string import lowercase as lc
a = 'a'
for old, new in zip(glob('a[a-z][a-z]'), (a+b+c for b in lc for c in lc)):
    if old != new:  rename(old, new)
```

but I'd like to solve the problem using only the shell, anyone with a trick?

I use Bash, but I'd like to see also solutions in different shells — on the other hand, I'm not interested in solutions that use a programming language different from the shell itself.

---

As kindly requested

```
aaa  aab  aad  aaf  aag  aah  aai  aam  ...
aaa  aab  aac  aad  aae  aaf  aag  aah  ...
```

the first two pairs correspond to a no-op, all the other pairs require a file rename:

```
$ mv aad aac
$ mv aaf aad
$ ...
```

Comment: My sequences in terms of shell commands are `a??` and `a{a..z}{a..z}`, I just want to match pairs in the two lists and, if they are different, rename the file — of course MOST of the files will be renamed, as soon as there is a gap in the first sequence _all_ the following files must be renamed

Comment: just to understand. With a sequence : ... aaz aba aca acb acd .... does all ac* would have to be renamed ab* to continue the ab* sequence, or the renaming is only within the group of the first two letters ?

Comment: @AndreGelinas The old names are sorted, with gaps, the new names are sorted, w/o gaps. That's all. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52457189/2749397) by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) _exactly_ solves my probem.

Comment: ERRATA CORRIGE My sequences in terms of shell commands are `a[a-z][a-z]` and `a{a..z}{a..z}` — this way the sequence of _new names_ is not shorter than the sequence of _old names_.  Sorry for the carelessness, fortunately the question was however sufficiently clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build two arrays:

```
old_names=( a[a-z][a-z] )
new_names=( a{a..z}{a..z} )
```

then iterate over them in parallel:

```
for ((i=0; i < ${#old_names[@]}; i++ )); do
  old_name=${old_names[i]}
  new_name=${new_names[i]}
  # if [ -z "$new_name" ]; then
  #  break
  # fi
  if [ "$old_name" != "$new_name" ]; then
    mv -- "$old_name" "$new_name"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Just wondering why `[ -z "$old_name" ]` when you build array using `a??` glob

Comment: The glob result is _guaranteed_ to be sorted?  are there possible differences between different shells/implementations?

Comment: It's guaranteed to be sorted, but in a locale-dependent manner.

Comment: @anubhava Right, that's unnecessary. I got mixed up and was thinking that `i` was iterating over a sequence that was long enough for the longer of the two.

Comment: Switched to checking that `new_name` isn't empty as a precautionary measure, but the structure of the problem should guarantee that `new_names` is at least as long as `old_names`.

Comment: You must change '<=' to '<' in the for loop because you get mv: cannot stat '': No such file or directory.

Comment: It seems that the off-by-one loop is counter balanced by the extra test.  The final version should be w/o the extra test `[ -z "$old_name" ]` and `i < old_length`.

Comment: I'm going to edit and accept your answer to ① reflect the adjustment I made to my Q, ② adjust the upper limit of the for loop and ③ remove the _now_ unnecessary sanity check. Please revert my edit if you feel like that.